# Multiple select with single Group By query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have these 3 fields in the table.

> trans_date |  transaction_type | client_id

What I need is a count of entries by transaction_types for each date. For example,

> Date : 07/07/2015  total count : 6 transaction_type 1 count : 3 ,
>   transaction_type 2 count : 1,   transaction_type 3 count : 2 etc....

And I need this for all the dates grouped by each date.

Here's my current query,

```
SELECT count(id) as total_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=1) as type1_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=2) as type2_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=3) as type3_count
FROM tblTransactions
where client_id=1
GROUP BY date(trans_date/1000, 'unixepoch')
```

This returns weird numbers that doesn't match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using a `GROUP BY` on _both_ the date and the `transaction_type` columns.  I will not give a formal answer because your question, as of the time of writing this comment, is a mess.

Comment: could you put some sample data or create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sum function instead of subqueries

```
select date(trans_date/1000, 'unixepoch') d,  
       sum(case when transaction_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) type1_count,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) type2_count,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) type3_count 
    from tblTransactions
  where client_id=1
  group by d
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are getting weird values is that your sub queries are not filtered by date so you will get the total count for each transaction type. What you need is a correlated subquery that will get a paremeter from outer query:

```
SELECT count(id) as total_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=1 and trans_date=t.trans_date) as type1_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=2 and trans_date=t.trans_date) as type2_count,
    (select count(id) where transaction_type=3 and trans_date=t.trans_date) as type3_count
FROM tblTransactions t
where client_id=1
GROUP BY date(trans_date/1000, 'unixepoch')
```